# Form refreshes before getting data from input

Tags: php, forms, email

Every time I submit the form it refreshes, but doesn’t send the mail. I think, it cleans the input box before I get to make them into a variable, so then it goes to the validation `IF` and shows the `*Please don't leave blank parameters!` message.

Regarding the sending email code, it works, I tested it in other new made file without a form, just by opening the file and sending the mail as it is opened.

This is always an actual webhost provider with real info/links.

While you are at it, if you would be so kind, please tell me if I’m following any “Bad Practices”. Thanks in advance!

Code:

[image: Code screenshot]

(I use a real email address to test, as well as real webhost links at the form — changed for this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems to be on **Line 12**

In your `if` statement instead of using the single `=`, which assigns a value, instead you should be using double `==` to check the value.

As far as Bad Practices, I will say that your sanitize `function` inside your `if` is weird, functions should generally be written outside of logic loops, at the main level, or in `OOP` it should be at the root of the object.

Comment: It did work indeed but, there is a small problem after tho, it is that it can't now validate it. Like even if there is a blank input, it still go forward.